# recurring event on weekend day or bank holiday, change to next working day

Tags: org-mode, calendar

If there is a recurring event on weekend day or bank holiday, if there a way to change it to next working day?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you want (in terms of individual steps)?

Comment: It may be helpful to see how it is that I calculate business days (i.e., *excluding* certain defined holidays and weekends):  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7118/2287  Perhaps there is something in that solution that you could extract for your current needs ...